# How to get rid of the Close Button in the header of a Visio AnchorBar Window (VSTO)?

Tags: c#, vsto, visio

Okay I have made a VSTO for Visio that uses a AnchorBarAddon Window.

The code for creating the window is below:

```
if (parent == null || windowstates == null || Assigned) return false;
Window = null;
Window = parent.Windows.Add(
   bstrCaption: Caption,
   nFlags: windowstates,
   nType: (object)Visio.VisWinTypes.visAnchorBarAddon,
   nWidth: _content.Size.Width,
   bstrMergeID: _guid,
   bstrMergeClass: "",
   nMergePosition: 0
   );
int windowHandle = _content.Handle.ToInt32();
Win32.SetWindowLongW(windowHandle, Win32.GWL_STYLE, Win32.WS_CHILD | Win32.WS_VISIBLE);
Win32.SetParent(windowHandle, Window.WindowHandle32);
_content.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
Window.GetWindowRect(out int left, out int top, out int width, out int height);
Window.SetWindowRect(left, top, width + addWidth, height + addHeight);
```

The Window created sports that normal Close-Button top right which I do not want to have (screenshot)
How do I get rid of it?
Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: First google result on the topic, it is possible with some sketchy workarounds: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fa3118ed-ba37-4ee4-ba26-e81b7e2352c8/disable-close-button-from-custom-task-pane?forum=vsto

Comment: I already checked this link before asking my question as I did not found an answer there. I have decided to live with it. Direct Win32 API calls did not work either.